# detect clicking on hyperlinks inside PDF document

Tags: android, pdf, hyperlink

I am building an Android app that uses PDF plugin to view PDF, my question is :

Is there anyway to prevent Hyperlinks from opening web browser instead I want to open Native Activity when hyperlink is clicked.

To get the big picture, whenever the user clicks a link the app should get the data from that link and show it in an Activity.

The problem is I can't find anything related to this issue when using PDF reader plugins.

Comment: Then contact the developers of the "PDF reader plugins" and ask them. There is no device-wide "please use `ACTION_VIEW` properly for hyperlinks" setting that you could somehow manipulate. Only the developers of the plugins can tell you if they offer this for their own plugins and how to use it. Of course, this also assumes that you have properly set up your activity to respond to the hyperlinks in question, via an appropriate `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: thanks CommonsWare  I'll contact them, BTW am using demo from PlugPDF plugin do you suggest something else ?